# How to make api calls synchronously in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have four api calls to make. They should be in following order:

apiSyncDataToCloud;

apiSyncImagesToServer;

apiDeleteDataFromCloud;

apiSyncDataFromCloudInBackground;

Each one of them is to be called irrespective of the fact that previous one finishes successfully or fails.

Also, each one of them have success and failure completion blocks.

In success completion block database is updated.

All this process has to be performed in **background** and has **to be done** **a no of times**. 
Api calls are of course performed in background but once a call completes database update is performed on main thread thereby freezing the app.

So, I went with several solutions:

Tried following code:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;


[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
     [self apiSyncDataToCloud];
}];

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self apiSyncImages];
}];

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self apiDeleteDataFromCloud];
}];

[queue  addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self apiSyncDataFromCloudInBackground];
}];
```

But this only guarantees that api method calls will be performed in order. But their result follows no specific order. That is, method calls will be in the order specified but success block of apiSyncImagesToServer may be called before success block of apiSyncDataToCloud.

Then I went with following solution:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self apiSyncDataToCloud];
});
```

and in the success and failure blocks of apiSyncDataToCloud I have called apiSyncImagesToServer. This too did'nt work.

Now I am simply going with my last solution. I am just calling apiSyncDataToCloud.

In success completion block this method first updates the database and then calls other api.

In failure completion block this method simply makes the api call without updating the database.

For example-

structure of apiSyncDataToCloud is as follows:

```
-(void)apiSyncDataToCloud{

NSLog(@"method 1");

NSMutableDictionary *dicDataToBeSynced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
dicDataToBeSynced = [self getDataToBeSynced];

if (dicDataToBeSynced.count!=0) {
    if ([[StaticHelper sharedObject] isInternetConnected]) {

        [[ApiHandler sharedObject] postRequestWithJsonString:API_SYNC_DATA_TO_CLOUD andHeader:[UserDefaults objectForKey:kAuthToken] forHeaderField:kAccessToken andParameters:dicDataToBeSynced WithSuccessBlock:^(NSURLResponse *response, id resultObject, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Data synced successfully to server");
            [self updateColumnZSYNC_FLAGForAllTables];//updating db
            [self apiSyncImagesToServer];//api call


        } andFailureBlock:^(NSURLResponse *task, id resultObject, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Data syncing to cloud FAILED");
            [self apiSyncImagesToServer];//simply make api call without updating db

        }];
    }
}else{
    [self apiSyncImagesToServer];make api call even if no data to be synced found

}
```

}

Similary, inside apiSyncImagesToServer I am calling apiDeleteDataFromCloud.....

As a result my problem remained as it is. App freezes when it comes to success block updating db, downloading images...all operations being performed on main thread.

Plz let me know a cleaner and better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom queue and call request one by one. 
i.e.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue;//declare own queue

if (!myQueue) {//check if queue not exists
        myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue1", NULL); //create queue
}
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{[self YOUR_METHOD_NAME];});//call your method in queue block
```

If you want update some UI after receiving data then update UI on main Thread.

Answer (score 1):

1) Better to use `AFNetworking` for this kind of situations. Because AFNetworking provides better way to handle Main & Background Threads. 
AFNetworking supports success and failure blocks so you can do one by one WS Api calls from success and failure of previous WS Api call. So during this time period show progress HUD. Success of last API then update DB and hide progress HUD.

2) If you need to use `NSOperationQueue and NSInvocationOperation`
and follow this link. https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

Comment: i am of course making these api calls using AFNetworking. Success and failure blocks are executed on main thread. And I want the whole operaion, be it making api calls or executing success and failure blocks, to be performed on some background thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Api calls are of course performed in background but once a call
>   completes database update is performed on main thread thereby freezing
>   the app.

Then why not perform it in a separate queue?
Try using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //your code
});
```

to perform time-consuming tasks and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your code
});
```

to only update UI.

Comment: Yes I am currently following this approach. But I am waiting for some better option to come.